# PyQt QTest click on QMenu

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, python-unittest, qtestlib

In my PyQt app I have a **main menu**, which has the following structure:

```
Main Menu
|___
    |
    Language
    |       |
    |        Russian
    |       |
    |        English
    Exit
```

I want to perform a click on **Russian** to test if the language is changed. I have a link to **language_menu** in GUI

```
[...somewhere in MainWindow...]
self.language_menu = QtGui.QMenu()
[....]
```

so

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QTest import QTest
from gui import MainWindow

class TestMainWindow(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        self.ui = MainWindow()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app.deleteLater()

    def test_translation(self):
        menu = self.ui.language_menu
        rus_lang = menu.actions()[0]
        QTest.mouseClick(rus_lang, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
```

but it tells me that

> argument 1 has unexpected type 'QAction'

How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: `rus_lang.trigger()` or `rus_lang.toggle()`

Comment: @ekhumoro It worked! Write your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rus_lang.trigger()` or `rus_lang.toggle()` to activate the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

i think ekhumoro's answer is wrong because it misses the point of the test,
`rus_lang.trigger()` isnt interacting with the gui.

for me `QTest.mouseClick(rus_lang, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)`
works fine with `QButton` maybe `QAction` has diffrent API.